# How to fix tying to get property name in view problem

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, github, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to connect laravel to socialite form facebook and GitHub everything works well but at the end of the connection to the social network apps I want to  return to auth.register view with data from the social provider

[image]

I have tried sending it as an array and JSON to the view but still to no avail

function to get data from the social provider

```
    public function redirectToProvider($social)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($social)->redirect();
       // return dd($social);
      // return $social;
    }
```

function to handle result

```
 public function handleProviderCallback($social)
    {
        //$social = 'github';
        $gituser = Socialite::driver($social)->user();

        $user = User::where('provider_id', $gituser->getEmail())->first();

            if($user){
                \Auth::login($user, true); 
                return redirect($this->redirectTo);
             }else{
                  'nemail' => $gituser->getemail()]);
                return view('auth.register')->with('data', ['name' => $gituser->getName(), 'email' => $gituser->getemail()]); 
            }

    }
```

auth.register view

```
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }} {{$data->name}}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }} {{$data->email}} " required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I expect to result to be that the data from the social provided is inserted into my auth.register form field (Name, Email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filling the `$data` variable with an `array` and accessing it as an `object`.

Change `{{$data->name}}` in your blade to `{{$data['name']}}`

or modify the `$data` variable.

```
return view('auth.register')->with('data', (object)['name' => $gituser->getName(), 'email' => $gituser->getemail()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

the error is in `{{$data->name}}` where `data` is not an `object` which is logical as you pass data as

```
return view('auth.register')->with('data', ['name' => $gituser->getName(), 'email' => $gituser->getemail()]);
```

which is an `array` notation.

For accessing an array you need `[]`: `{{ data['name'] }}`